# How to pass the dynamic column name in django ORM values

Tags: django, django-orm

I have  `data = request.POST` (i.e **`<QueryDict: {u'device': [u'Camera '], u'todate': [u'2018-05-18'], u'fromdate': [u'2018-04-19']}>`** ) and 
**`device = data.get('device', None)`** which is a column name in database table and a user selected value(which change based on user selection)

Monitor.objects.values(device)

Now I got the error like **`Cannot resolve keyword u'Camera ' into field. Choices are: Camera`**

**`how can I convert column name stored in, device variable into a actual column`**

Comment: Where is your model ?

Comment: you have a space in the `'Camera '`

Comment: model is Monitor

Comment: show entire model fields ?

Comment: @BearBrown thank you very much. You are correct. now its working